# "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidValueError: not a LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: not an Object" on page load while using

Tags: angular

I am using the agm-map library for google map integration in angular 7, so for manual search on input box I am calling geocode API of google but in order to reflect the map with search location I am using `[(fitBounds)]="viewport"`. But when I am trying to load the page I am getting a console error -

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): InvalidValueError: not a
>   LatLngBounds or LatLngBoundsLiteral: not an Object

when i tried to remove the `[(fitBounds)]="viewport"` then there is no console error but on manual search my map is not reflecting the search location.

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [scrollwheel]="true" [zoom]="zoom" [(fitBounds)]="viewport" [fullscreenControl]="true" [mapTypeControl]="true">
 <agm-marker [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude" [markerDraggable]="true" (dragEnd)="markerDragEnd($event)"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

I don't want the error message on my console also manual location should also get reflected on map. Please help me with the solution.